# Do automations have a time limit where they crash?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, timeout

I am uncertain if this question was asked somewhere but atleast I did not find a post that covers it within a few minutes of searching on documentation and stackexchange. [Closest question I found](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245096/marketing-cloud-automation-studio-scripty-activity-getting-time-out/245101#245101)

- Do Automations have a time limit where they will timeout?

  - Can I have multiple *(lets say 5 activities that run 20 minutes one after the other)* in an automation?
- Is the time limit for activities really 30minutes or is it 15minutes?

Comment: I believe the only activities that have limits called out in the documentation are the SSJS activity and the Query activity (30 mins)

Comment: Yes, Automations cannot time out - only the pieces inside of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built automations using queries and wait steps, when I need to sync data more often than once every hour. E.g. Query - 10 min wait - Query - 10 min wait... etc. These work flawlessly.

There is a limit of 30 minutes for single queries: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000247597&type=1

Similar I also see this limit for Script activities, guessing this applies across all activity types. However I can't find any official documentation on this (other than on Query activities above)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that limits on activities only apply to script & query.

Comment: I also see the other activity types being less prone to long execution times

Comment: I think the better solution in your case it to schedule Automation more frequent than an hour. It's possible via API.

Answer (score 0):

30 minutes is the standard timeout limit for queries in an Automation. If you have Proactive Monitoring Service from SF, they can increase that limit upon request after all efforts of tuning your queries/redesigning can't remedy the situation.

After failing all efforts on our end to tune the query, we raised a Case for Developer Support. Salesforce tried tuning the query on the backend but could not get the desired result. Then they increased the timeout limit.
(Speaking from first hand experience)